# Tailwind doesn't pick up my scss defined color in the config

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css

I have this in my scss :

```
$yellow: 248 239 0;
@layer base {
  :root {
    --color-green: 60 255 208;
    --color-gray: 148 148 148;
    --color-yellow: $yellow;
  }
}
```

and this is my tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "custom-green": 'rgb(var(--color-green) / <alpha-value>)',
        "custom-gray": 'rgb(var(--color-gray) / <alpha-value>)',
        "custom-yellow": 'rgb(var(--color-yellow) / <alpha-value>)'
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

For some reason gray and green work fine. However if I define my color like I do with the yellow in a variable for some reason it does not work. What could the issue be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a sufficiently modern version of Sass, you might be finding that the [`--color-yellow` CSS custom property does not have the value you expect](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/declarations#custom-properties) and is compiling to:

```css
:root {
  --color-yellow: $yellow;
}
```

Consider interpolating the value in Sass like:

```scss
$yellow: 248 239 0;
@layer base {
  :root {
    --color-yellow: #{$yellow};
  }
}
```

Then it should compile to a three digit space-separated list:

```css
:root {
  --color-yellow: 248 239 0;
}
```